# Specify the return type for a ctypes call (in python) to a fortran function that returns an array of doubles

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I'm trying to use the ctypes module to call, from within a python program, a (fortran) library of linear algebra routines that I have written. I have successfully imported the library and can call my *subroutines* and functions that return a single value. My problem is calling functions that return an array of doubles. I can't figure out how to specify the return type. As a result, I get segfaults whenever I call a function like that.

Here's a minimum working example, a routine to take the cross product between two 3-vectors:

```
!****************************************************************************************
! Given vectors a and b, c = a x b
function cross_product(a,b)
real(dp) a(3), b(3), cross_product(3)

cross_product = (/a(2)*b(3) - a(3)*b(2), &
                  a(3)*b(1) - a(1)*b(3), &
                  a(1)*b(2) - a(2)*b(1)/)
end function cross_product
```

Here's my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from ctypes import byref, cdll, c_double
testlib =  cdll.LoadLibrary('/Users/hart/codes/celib/trunk/libutils.so')
cross = testlib.vector_matrix_utilities_mp_cross_product_

a = (c_double * 3)()
b = (c_double * 3)()
a[0] = c_double(0.0)
a[1] = c_double(1.0)
a[2] = c_double(2.0)
b[0] = c_double(1.0)
b[1] = c_double(3.0)
b[2] = c_double(2.0)

print a,b
cross.restype = c_double * 3
print cross.restype
print cross(byref(a),byref(b))
```

And here's the output:

```
goku:~/python/ctypes> ./test_example.py 
<__main__.c_double_Array_3 object at 0x10399b710> <__main__.c_double_Array_3 object at 0x10399b7a0>
<class '__main__.c_double_Array_3'>
Segmentation fault: 11
goku:~/python/ctypes>
```

I've tried different permutations for the line "cross.restype = ..." but I can't figure out what should actually go there. Thanks for reading this question. --Gus

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [f2py](http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/)?

Comment: @SethMMorton Because it cannot handle derived data types. My code is pretty "modern" with lots of "objects," not just numbers and arrays. For derived data types, this package seems to do the trick in most instances. https://github.com/jameskermode/f90wrap

Answer (score 1):

The compiler may return a pointer to the array, or the array descriptor... So, when mixing languages, you should always use `bind(C)` except when the wrapper specifically supports Fortran. And (not surprisingly) `bind(C)` functions cannot return arrays. You could theoretically allocate the array and return `type(c_ptr)` to it, but how to dealocate it after the use?

So my suggestion is to use a subroutine.

Comment: I have lots and lots of code that I wanted to call from python. Re-writing it all to avoid derived data types and to always be in a subroutine isn't a very practical solution in my case. However, this new wrapper seems to work in many (but not all yet) instances. https://github.com/jameskermode/f90wrap

Comment: You can even post that as an answer add some comments about it. I didn't know about this package until today.

Answer (score 0):

With gfortran the function call has a hidden argument:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> testlib = CDLL('./libutils.so')
>>> cross = testlib.cross_product_

>>> a = (c_double * 3)(*[0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
>>> b = (c_double * 3)(*[1.0, 3.0, 2.0])
>>> c = (c_double * 3)()
>>> pc = pointer(c)

>>> cross(byref(pc), a, b)
3
>>> c[:]
[-4.0, 2.0, -1.0]
```

But [Vladimir's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664115/205580) to use `bind(C)` and a subroutine is the better way to go.

FYI, arrays become pointers in C function calls, so using `byref` is redundant. I needed `byref` and `pointer` in order to create a `double **` for the hidden argument.